# Implementing add_all_at_index in a singly-linked list

Tags: rust

I am implementing a singly-linked list. I want to add a method `add_all_at_index` which will take a new list and an index, insert the new list at the specified index and rearrange the tail of the current list to follow after the new list.

Assume the current list is is `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Calling `add_all_at_index` at position `2` with list `[8,9,10]` should result in `[1,2,8,9,10,3,4,5]`.

I'm especially having trouble in assigning the old tail of the list after the new list. I do not know how to append `[3,4,5]` to the node with value `10` in the list.

The algorithm I am trying to implement is

- Save the current next of the node at (index - 1) in a variable called `current_next`
- Set the next of node at (index - 1) to the head of the list
- Iterate to the last of the newly added list and set its next to the `current_next`.

I am having trouble accomplishing the last step. Below is the code I came up with:

```
use std::fmt::*;

fn main() {
    let list: List<i32> = List::new();
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct Node<T: Debug> {
    pub element: T,
    pub next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
pub struct List<T: Debug> {
    pub head: Option<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T: Debug> List<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List { head: None }
    }

    pub fn add_all_at_index(&mut self, list_to_add: List<T>, index: usize) {
        if index > 0 {
            let nth_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(index).take(); // Gets a mutable reference to node at index
            nth_node.map(|node| {
                let current_next = node.next.take(); // I store a reference to the next of nth node,
                node.next = list_to_add.head.map(|node| Box::new(node));

                // The 3rd step in the algorithm I mentioned above.
                let last_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(self.length()); // This line does not compile. Getting multiple errors in this line
                last_node.map(|node| node.next = current_next);
            });
        } else {
            self.head = list_to_add.head
        }
    }

    fn get_nth_node_mut(&mut self, n: usize) -> Option<&mut Node<T>> {
        let mut nth_node = self.head.as_mut();
        for _ in 0..n {
            nth_node = match nth_node {
                None => return None,
                Some(node) => node.next.as_mut().map(|node| &mut **node),
            }
        }
        nth_node
    }

    pub fn length(&self) -> usize {
        let mut count = 0;
        let mut current_node = self.head.as_ref();
        while let Some(node) = current_node {
            count = count + 1;
            current_node = node.next.as_ref().map(|node| &**node)
        }
        count
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
warning: unused variable: `list`
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |     let list: List<i32> = List::new();
  |         ^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_variables)] on by default
  = note: to avoid this warning, consider using `_list` instead

error[E0500]: closure requires unique access to `self` but `*self` is already borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:26:26
   |
25 |             let nth_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(index).take(); // Gets a mutable reference to node at index
   |                            ---- borrow occurs here
26 |             nth_node.map(|node| {
   |                          ^^^^^^ closure construction occurs here
...
31 |                 let last_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(self.length()); // This line does not compile. Getting multiple errors in this line
   |                                 ---- borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
...
34 |         } else {
   |         - borrow ends here

error[E0502]: cannot borrow `**self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:31:55
   |
31 |                 let last_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(self.length()); // This line does not compile. Getting multiple errors in this line
   |                                 ----                  ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
   |                                 |
   |                                 mutable borrow occurs here
32 |                 last_node.map(|node| node.next = current_next);
33 |             });
   |             - mutable borrow ends here
```

Is this even the right approach to implement `add_all_at_index`?

I even tried implementing an iterator that returns a mutable reference to a node but I was not able to do that either. I have pasted the entire code in a gist at https://gist.github.com/hardvain/32fca033bb61a5e3bf8bbeeb32fbbd5e

Comment: I would like to know why the question was down voted. I am unable to see who down voted or why it was down voted. If there is a mistake in the way I asked the question, I will correct it.

Comment: I think that's because you did not provide any code for your function. Edit the question to show what you've tried so far, and that will be ok I guess. Specifically, you need to add an MVCE.

Comment: You say you have trouble, but not what kind of trouble. Compiler errors? Incorrect behavior?

Comment: @all: Thank you for the guidance. I will update the question now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the solution:

```
pub fn add_all_at_index(&mut self, list_to_add: List<T>, index: usize) {
    if index > 0 {
        let tail = {
            let nth_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(index).take();
            nth_node.map(|node| {
                let current_next = node.next.take();
                node.next = list_to_add.head.map(|node| Box::new(node));
                current_next
            })
        };

        if let Some(current_next) = tail {
            let n = self.length();
            let last_node = self.get_nth_node_mut(n);
            last_node.map(|node| node.next = current_next);
        }
    } else {
        self.head = list_to_add.head
    }
}
```

Ugly, right? Right. Getting this working required several changes:

- I moved step 3 (reattaching the tail of the list) outside of the closure passed to `map`, so that `nth_node` (which borrows `self`) wouldn't still be alive when you try to borrow `self` again to get the length.
- I therefore had to save `current_next`, so I had the closure return it, and stored the result of `map` in a new variable called `tail`. So `tail` is an `Option<Box<Node<T>>>`.
- I wrapped the tail-reattaching part in an `if let` to destructure `tail` and get `current_next` back out.
- Then, I separated `self.get_nth_node_mut(self.length())` into two statements to resolve the remaining borrowing error.

---

Some followup suggestions:

- Using `.map()` for side effects and then ignoring the return value is unidiomatic. Use `if let` to run code on the content of an `Option`.
- You're ignoring all the `None` cases. If you try to call `add_all_at_index` with an `index` that is out of range, nothing happens to `self` and `list_to_add` is just lost. The function should probably return a `Result` of some kind, or perhaps a `bool`.
- `.take()` is for getting an `Option<T>` out of a `&mut Option<T>`. It doesn't do anything useful to an `Option<&mut T>`.
- `|node| Box::new(node)` is just `Box::new`.
- Because the first node is boxed but none of the others are, you will have to write a lot of special case code, and there's not a transparent conversion between a Node and a List.
- Using `get_nth_node_mut` in the implementation of `add_all_at_index` almost forces you to traverse the list twice. Because it's implemented on `List` instead of on `Node`, you can't easily get a reference to the last element of the list, so you end up calling `length()` (making the total number of traversals 3) and then `get_nth_node_mut` again to dig up the last element.

Some of the ugliness can be mitigated by careful interface design -- for instance, this method becomes cleaner if `List` has a `split_at_index` method -- but some of it is just due to the fact that *linked lists* are ugly. *Particularly* ugly in Rust, because the language forbids shared mutable references, even temporarily. You would have to use `unsafe` to write many linked list operations in Rust the same way you would in C.

If you have not already, please read [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/). This book addresses many of the subtleties that arise when you try to implement a linked list in Rust.

Comment: This is a really detailed explanation. Thanks a lot for the suggestions as well. I will update my code accordingly. Once again thanks.